Help with using multiple ips from one port of router and accessing a website from those
In our institution ISP provided us with a modem with only 1 working port. But 5 ips can be accessed using that port by directly plugging in network cable to a pc. Our organization's website only allows users having those 5 ip addresses to access it. Everything is fine as long as we only work 1 person at a time by plugging pc to that port.
But when we used a switch in between and tried plugging in 5 pcs with those 5 static ips, we are not able to access the website as it says invalid domain. We can access the internet   which means the ips are working. I need help accessing that website as there are multiple users which need work at the same time.
I don't know if its safe to post those ip addresses here. Also I have no experience in networking. Any help? TY.
EDIT. When I checked my IP address using findmyip, it shows another address. Not the one I set in my network connection. How do I correct it?

it says invalid domain seems to indicate a DNS problem which is off topic here for working above the transport layer. You likely need a NAT router which maps any address from a new, private LAN to a single outgoing IP address. We cannot recommend any specific products here, so I'm not sure how we can help you further.


when we used a switch in between and tried plugging in 5 pcs with those 5 static ips, we are not able to access the website as it says invalid domain.

You need to talk to your institution ISP as there seems to be a problem with DNS, possibly in connection with DHCP.
One possible alternative would be a NAT router connecting the single, working IP address to a new 'private' subnet that you connect multiple clients to. The NAT router effectively hides the private subnet from the upstream network.

I forgot to say that I am able to access that website. But it says just "domain not matched. License key violation". But while plugging directly to the router and using that same static ip, I am able to work by logging into the website. I think the problem is that website recognizes something is wrong while using the switch. Therefore it does not show the login page. Also I use their ip address directly to access the website.

Then there's only that single IP address whitelisted, not all five.

I can access that website from all 5 ips while connecting directly to the router. But not through switch. Meaning if there is a switch between the router & pc, this message appears. Does it mean the ip address has been changed. But ipconfig command shows the same static ip I set.

@FoxMulder, through the router, you probably use NAT and everything appears to be from a single address, and that is the allowed address, with a switch, you are using other addresses that are not allowed. You need to correct what other addresses should be allowe.

Why not just use the router properly if it all works when you use the router?
A switch connected between your PCs and your router should not cause your IP addresses to change, assuming that your router is setup to share the IP address in question as it likely is by default.

I configured the IP after connecting through the switch. I checked it using ipconfig. The only difference is that its not directly connected to the router. Everything else is the same. But the website recognizes it somehow.    I can't use the router because it has only one port that is working. That's how the ISP configured it. There are 6 users who need to use the website at the same time. So we tried a switch in between. @FrameHowitzer.

Now I checked my IP using find my IP. It shows a different IP address. How can I make it the same as the one I set? @RonMaupin

the website recognizes it somehow - applications and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

I just want to know why I can't access the website when everything is the same except for a switch in between router and pc. Is there anyway to configure that switch?

If the switch is managed then you might need to configure it properly - we cannot know what you're using unless you're providing more detail.

The modem is TEJAS TJ2100N-11G. I think its customized as it says in their webpage. No wifi. Switch is dlink des-1008c
